# Why doesn't my CNN's accuracy/loss change during training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

My goal is to train a convolutional neural network to recognise the images present in the [mnist sign language dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datamunge/sign-language-mnist/data).  Here is my attempt to process the data and train the model

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2
import random
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
import cv2
import keras
import sys
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import optimizers
import json

train_df = pd.read_csv("data/sign_mnist_train.csv")
test_df = pd.read_csv("data/sign_mnist_test.csv")
X = np.array(train_df.drop(["label"], axis=1))
y = np.array(train_df[["label"]])
X = X.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)
X = tf.cast(X, tf.float32)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(28, (3,3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(24, activation = 'softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='RMSprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, validation_split=0.2)
```

and after running this I get this result

```
Epoch 1/10
687/687 [==============================] - 4s 6ms/step - loss: 174.9729 - accuracy: 0.0438 - val_loss: 174.6281 - val_accuracy: 0.0382
Epoch 2/10
687/687 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 174.9779 - accuracy: 0.0433 - val_loss: 174.6281 - val_accuracy: 0.0382
Epoch 3/10
687/687 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 174.9777 - accuracy: 0.0433 - val_loss: 174.6281 - val_accuracy: 0.0382
```

and this continues for the remaining 7 epochs. My model is slightly different from what I have provided (for brevity) but this sequential model has the same issue, which makes me suspect that the issue must come before the `model = Sequential()` line. Furthermore, I have tried countless combinations of optimizers/loss and all those do is make the accuracy/loss converge to slightly different numbers, so I doubt that's the problem.

Comment: Any reason you specify `validation_split` while providing separate `train` and `test` datasets?

Comment: Oh my bad, you don't use `test_df` at all, I take it back.

Comment: Probably it has to do with your data. How does your data and labels look like?

Comment: Initially `X.shape = (27455, 784)` and `y.shape = (27455, 1)`  but after reshaping `X.shape = TensorShape([27455, 28, 28, 1])`. X is the data, Y is the labels. X is 27455 examples of a 784 pixel (28x28) image

Comment: You need to use categorical crossentropy not BCE.

Comment: You need to 1) normalize your input features 2) use categorical cross-entropy loss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of potential is that you use `loss='binary_crossentropy'` rather than `loss='CategoricalCrossentropy'`.

Besides, you defined the split datasets for training and testing, but you again defined it as `model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, validation_split=0.2)` to split datasets with 20% for validation and 80% for training.